# How to convert a (somewhat complex) Postgresql statement to SQLAlchemy ORM in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I've been given a task which I find a bit hard to handle, and I'm looking for some guidance as both how to solve my problem and where to find similar information on how to solve similar problems.

So, my task is to query a database using the SQLAlchemy ORM, by converting a relatively complex query to SQLAlchemy code. So instead of doing a connection.execute("select a,b,c as sea from A,B,C where...")
Edit: I have a connection to a db_session object and I  should do something like
`db_session.query(B.email,B.tel,A.createdC.a_name.label("C")).join(B, end_(B.id=A.B_id...).filter(wf_id=db_session.query(wf.id.filter(id='12345'))`  etc.

The postgres query that I have to convert is quoted in the code section below.
I'm having special trouble with the following bits:
`cast(cfields as json)->>'name'`

`left join C on C.id=A.C_id`

Here's the code. If you could help me with structuring the code, and especially with guiding me to a resource for a beginner to learn more about the SQLAlchemy ORM, I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
select B.email,B.tel,A.created,C.a_name as C,result,cfields ,
       cast(cfields as json)->>'name' as gname
from A
         join B on B.id=A.B_id
         left join C on C.id=A.C_id
where wf_id=(select id from wf where uuid=`12345`)
and c4_id=(select id from c4 where uuid=`54321`)
  and A.result='complete'
order by A.created asc;
```

Update1:
So far I've come to this point:

```py
db_session.query(B.email, B.tel, A.created, C.a_name.label("C"),
                 A.result, A.cfields, A.cfields['name'].label("gname")).join(
    A, and_(A.B_id == B.id).join(
        C, C.id == A.C_id, isouter=True).filter(
        A.wf_id == (db_session.query(wf.id).filter(wf.uuid == '12345'))
    ).order_by(A.created)
)
```

My current problem is that
`A.cfields['name'].label("gname")` is not working as a conversion for `cast(cfields as json)->>'name' as gname`
Any ideas about how to work with that?

Thanks a lot for your time,
Bill

Comment: Two things. Back ticks do not work in Postgresql. But more important, why do you want to do this? Why scramble a decent and working SQL script that is declarative and easy to read into a mystic sequence of proprietary imperative calls?

Comment: Ah, thanks about the backticks, had forgotten about it! 
As for the ORM, I've been told that it's more secure and integrates better with the current codebase. It's also a good exercise for me to get used to using the SQLA ORM, since I've just joined the project and need to familiarise myself with the codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after lots of trial-and-error, googling and reading docs, I reached the solution and I'm gonna post it here just in case anyone else needs it.

So the answer to casting the attribute I was querying to JSON and getting a specific value was to first import cast and JSON from sqlalchemy and then cast it before trying to get a value by giving it a key.

So, here's what I did:

```py
from sqlalchemy import cast, JSON

db_session.query(B.email, B.tel, A.created, C.a_name.label("C"),
                 A.result, A.cfields, cast(A.cfields,JSON)['name'].label("gname")).join(
    A, and_(A.B_id == B.id).join(
        C, C.id == A.C_id, isouter=True).filter(
        A.wf_id == (db_session.query(wf.id).filter(wf.uuid == '12345'))
    ).order_by(A.created)
)
```